# How to Construct Swap Gates from Permutation Matrix?

Tags: quantum-gate, circuit-construction, quantum-circuit

This is a follow-up question from [here](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/21676/understanding-constant-multiplication-circuit-for-binary-field-how-to-construc).

Let's say after an LUP decomposition, we have an 8x8 permutation matrix:

$ P^{-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}  $

How to construct the corresponding swap gates?

Note: I think this question is different from [the other question](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/9365/decomposing-a-w1-qubit-permutation-gate-into-w-qubit-permutation-gates-s) because the question in that link is in the form of unitary matrix ($2^n$ x $2^n$) while here is a $n$ x $n$.

Answer (score 2):

There's a thing named [elementary row operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elementary_matrix#Elementary_row_operations), where the swap gate I think corresponds to the *Row Switching* operation. So what you need to do is change your matrix step by step into an identity matrix.

For your case, $\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}=swap(2,3) *\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}=swap(2,3)*swap(3,5)*
\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1\\
\end{bmatrix}
...$

Where I use the $swap(i,j)$ representing the action of switching two rows. Finally, you will find out the corresponding swap gate.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer! I have questions though: 1) your matrix is 7x8 while mine is 8x8, it's just a mistype, right? 2) Is there an algorithmic, fixed way to obtain the sequence of swap gates, or is it heuristic?

Comment: @prairie99 typo, sorry. The way I find the swap gate is just by changing the matrix more and more like the identity matrix. That is, first fix the $(1,1)$ element to be 1, then the $(2,2)$ element to be 1, then ...